# ratio of alcohol to water

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cask initially contains pure alcohol up to the brim. The cask can be emptied by removing exactly 5 liters at a time . Each time this is done, the cask must be filled back to the brim with water. The capacity of the cask is 15 liters. When the cask is completely emptied and filled back to the brim two times, what is the ratio of alcohol to water in the cask?

now  i did not understand problem,if  it says that cask can be emptied by  removing exactly $5$ liter it means that,right now there is $5$  liter alcohol but  when it is removed and  water is  poured,then we have not  alcohol and ratio of alcohol to water  how could i calculate?i did not understand condition of problem,please could help me

Comment: The "completely emptied two times" is confusing as the cask never becomes empty. I assume that (starting with 15 litres of alcohol), you repeat the procedure of extracting 5 litres of liquid and filling up with 5 litres of water six times.

Comment: @giorgi: There are 15 litres in there and you do it in chunks of 5 at a time. Remove 5 and you have 10 liters of alcohol is my interpretation.

Comment: i did not understand too,so it means that  problem is asked  wrongly right.conditions

Comment: initially contains pure alcohol what does means?

Comment: aaa,it means that  amount of  alcohol is multiply of $5$?  or $10$ or $15$

Comment: Note that there's probably an unspoken assumption that if you remove 5 litres of alcohol and add 5 litres of water you end up with the starting volume of 15 litres. This isn't quite true, so beware limitations of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 15 liters of alcohol in the cask initially. Then you remove 5 liters. You have 10 liters of alcohol and you have to pour the water back so the cask is full again. Then you have a mixture of 10 liters of alco and 5 liters of water.

They tell you to remove 5 liters again. Assuming the mixture is uniform, you remove $5$ litres of the mixture, which is $5\cdot \frac{10}{15}=\frac{10}{3}$ litres of alco and $5\cdot \frac{5}{15}=\frac{5}{3}$ litres of water. And then you pour 5 litres of water. So finally you have $10-\frac{10}{3}=6 \frac{2}{3}$ litres of alco and $5-\frac{5}{3}+5=8\frac{1}{3}$ litres of water.

So the ratio is $\frac{6 \frac{2}{3}}{8\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{\frac{20}{3}}{\frac{25}{3}} = 4/5$.

Comment: correct i understood now\

Comment: i have one question when we have mixture of ratio  $4:3$,and we remove  n liter,how much is in this $n$ liter each one?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The word "completely" could be really misleading in your task.

Comment: There is $4n/7$ of the first and $3n/7$ of the second.

Comment: i see ,because each one is $4/7$ and $3/7$  right

Comment: only one thing  why we can't remove reversely?i mean $10/3$ water and $5/3$ alcohol?

Comment: The ratio alcohol:water is 2:1 after the first step. So you remove $2n/3=2\cdot 5/3=10/3$ of alcohol and $1n/3=1\cdot 5 / 3 = 5/3$ of water.

Comment: aa i see,i have asked    this question before

Answer (score 3):

Since at each step you remove one third of the mixture and don't fill back any alcohol, the absolute amount of alcohol gets multiplied with $\frac23$ at each turn, so after $n$ turns, the absolute amount of alcohol is $\left(\frac23\right)^n\cdot 15$ litres and the rest is water.

Comment: Neatly avoiding the lack of clarity as to how many times the cask is watered down!